# Why are changes to a list, in an instance of a python 3 class, global?

Tags: python-3.x

Why when I create a class with a list, the list and its contents become global

```
class A:
    my_list = []
    string = ""
    def add(self, data):
        self.string += "a"
        self.my_list.append(data)
    def print_list(self):
        print(self.string)
        print(self.my_list)

a = A()
b = A()
a.add("test")
a.print_list()
b.print_list()
```

Both a and b will print the list that was created by a.add

```
# results of a.print_list
xa
['test']

# results of b.print_list
x
['test']
```

So my question is, is this normal for python3, or a bug. 
Doesnt seem right to me that only the list is modified globally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the explaining:

> Objects have individuality, and multiple names (in multiple scopes) can be bound to the same object. This is known as aliasing in other languages. This is usually not appreciated on a first glance at Python, and can be safely ignored when dealing with immutable basic types (numbers, strings, tuples). However, aliasing has a possibly surprising effect on the semantics of Python code involving mutable objects such as lists, dictionaries, and most other types. This is usually used to the benefit of the program, since aliases behave like pointers in some respects. For example, passing an object is cheap since only a pointer is passed by the implementation; and if a function modifies an object passed as an argument, the caller will see the change — this eliminates the need for two different argument passing mechanisms as in Pascal.

[From oficial Python 3 docs](https://docs.python.org/3.4/tutorial/classes.html#a-word-about-names-and-objects)

And this is the solution:

> (...) use an instance variable instead (...)

Like this:

```
class Dog:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.tricks = [] # creates a new empty list for each dog

    def add_trick(self, trick):
        self.tricks.append(trick)
```

Result of above code:

```
>>> d = Dog('Fido')
>>> e = Dog('Buddy')
>>> d.add_trick('roll over')
>>> e.add_trick('play dead')
>>> d.tricks ['roll over']
>>> e.tricks ['play dead']
```

---

In your example, you should move your `my_list = []` declaration to the init function...

```
class A:
    string = ""

    def __init__(self):
        self.my_list = []

    def add(self, data):
        self.string += "a"
        self.my_list.append(data)
    def print_list(self):
        print(self.string)
        print(self.my_list)

a = A()
b = A()
a.add("test")
a.print_list()
b.print_list()
```

Hope this help.

Regards

Answer (score 1):

Strings are immutable so

```
    self.string += "a"
```

creates a new object and binds it to `self.string`

---

This is clearly mutating the list in place

```
    self.my_list.append(data)
```

Perhaps more interesting is that

```
    self.my_list += [data]
```

also mutates the list

---

The general rule is that `__iadd__` **does** behave differently for mutable vs immutable objects